# Qt C++ Convert QString to long

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to convert QString into long using this commands:

```
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        QString content = stream.readAll();
        qDebug() << "String: " << content;
        bool ok;
        long long a = content.toLong(&ok, 10);
        qDebug() << a;
        file.close();
```

But I get following output from qDebug:

```
String:  "123451234512345
" 
0
```

It seems this qstring can't be converted into long long variable because I always get 0. I tried to convert smaller number like 1234 and it works, but when I try to convert this big number then I have problems. Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An unsigned long (32 bits) has a maximum value of 4294967295 - half that for a signed long - which your value is exceeding. You should use the `toLongLong` function instead.

Answer (score 3):

You're going beyond the bounds of a long. The Number in the string is too big. Look up the max size for a long. try tolonglong .
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toLongLong